# How to always open file in the same editor?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I switch between files (Using ctrl-n for examples) in different editors, intellij always opens the file in the original editor the tab for the file is located. Coming from a vim background this seems counter intuitive for me. Is there a way to force intellij to always open the file in the same editor window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please vote for the following related issues:

- [IDEA-67559](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67559) Opening a file when there are multiple file groups may re-open in a different group rather than opening in the current group
- [IDEA-81628](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81628) Navigation within same file mistakenly leaves split editor

Answer (score 2):

When using Ctrl-Shift-N to open the desired file, Shift-Enter to confirm will maintain the focused tab group.

Comment: Unfortunately this is no longer the case. `Shift-Enter` will open the file in a new split.