# Intellij Idea: how to open files in specific tabs?

Tags: intellij-idea

Short: how to open `FileA` in a Tab Group 1, `FileB` in a Tab Group 2 and `FileC` in a Tab Group 3 without making too many moves?

The problem: I have a wide screen split into three editing groups. When I press <kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+N</kbd> and type the name of the file or class to open, I expect it to be opened in the currently active pane. This however happens in 33% of the cases - depending if the file is present that current group.

So I am editing `FileA` in Group 1  and I want to open `FileC` in Group 3. I navigate to Group 3 and press <kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd> to open the files. It unfortunately pops out in Group 1, the file which I was editing. Which is a bit frustrating, because I lose focus of what I was working on. I then drag this file into Group 3. And then I try to reopen the file I was working on in Group 1. Which won't necessary open in Group 1. So I have to do the moves again.

The best thing I found was to enable bookmarks in the files I want to edit and after opening them, rearrange the tabs.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13927121/104891?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Right-o sir, thank you